# Rails standardize URI.encode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, uriencoding

If `{"foo" => "yo%20daddy"}` comes through the url, params[:foo] plays nicely with URI.encode, resolving to:

```
URI.encode("yo daddy")
#=> "yo%20daddy"
```

However if "foo" comes as a JSON parameter, it does not.

```
URI.encode("yo%20daddy")
#=> "yo%2520daddy"
```

A solution to standardize this is

```
URI.encode(URI.decode("yo daddy"))
#=> "yo%20daddy"

URI.encode(URI.decode("yo%20daddy"))
#=> "yo%20daddy"
```

But that seems downright silly. Any better ideas?

Comment: I believe the problem is on the client side which is sending URL encoded data as JSON which is incorrect. Rails is decoding / encoding based on what the client says it is sending. So I would ask the client to send the right data or set the correct data-type.